# Rails 4 - .find_by_id() gives method missing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm new to rails development and have been messing around with the rails console to get used to it. When I try to find a record by `.find_by_id()` it throws a method missing error.

It seems like there is something wrong with the active record gem but I ran `gem update` which updated the active record gem and am still getting the same error...
I'm not sure what exactly the problem is.

Help is much appreciated!!

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_by_id' for #<Class:0x007fdd03515238>
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):1
```

Comment: Does the class on which you're calling `.find_by_id` inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`?

Comment: it should be a built in rails method like `find()`.. how would I check it's inheritance?

Comment: Find the file for the class in question (likely in `app/models/your_class.rb`) and be sure `class YourClass < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: Can you post the contents of the class's file, and the path at which that file is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `find_by_id` is deprecated, and when finding by a column the syntax is now `find_by(column: value)`. For id, I think the `find` method is what you're looking for. `Model.find(x)` should return the record where `id = x`, or an error if it one isn't found. You could still use `find_by(id: x)` though.

Comment: True, but `.find_by_id()` should still work.  If `.find_by_id()` is missing (for whatever reason), `.find` might also be missing.

Comment: thank you, `find_by` doesn't return an error when a record doesn't exist but it returns the 1st record when a record can't be found...

[edit]: when used properly `find_by("column_name":"value")` does work properly and just returns nil when no record exists!

Answer (score 0):

The method you're looking for is simply `find(id)`.

Comment: `find()` works but when there is no record it spits back a lot of errors which can cause problems later on in production if a user is looking for a record that doesn't exist, so I need `find_by_id`